# Cannot insert custom links in TextView

Tags: android, hyperlink, textview, linkify

I am trying to insert links to TextView in order to make them start a new activity. I wrote a method to my `Utils` class to do that:

```
public static final String tagPattern = "#([^ ]+)";
public static final String tagReplace = "<a href=\"org.openihs.seendroid://display/tag/$1/\">#$1</a>";
public static final String userPattern = "@([^ ]+)";
public static final String userReplace = "<a href=\"org.openihs.seendroid://display/user/$1/\">@$1</a>";
static public void linkify(TextView view) {
    String text = view.getText().toString();
    text = text.replaceAll(Utils.tagPattern, Utils.tagReplace);
    text = text.replaceAll(Utils.userPattern, Utils.userReplace);
    view.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
    view.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));
    Log.d("SeenDroid", text);
    Linkify.addLinks(view, Linkify.ALL);
}
```

An example output (to the logcat) is:

```
foo <a href="org.openihs.seendroid://display/tag/bar/">#bar</a> baz http://google.fr/
```

And the real UI gives http://google.fr/ as a link (expected behavior), but `#bar` as a normal text (unexpected behavior).

The TextView is in a ListView.

Any idea to solve that issue?

Regards,
ProgVal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linkify works a little different than the way you're trying to use it.

```
public static final String AUTHORITY = "your_package.your_content_provider";
public static final Uri CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse("content://" + AUTHORITY + "/tag/");
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(tagPattern);
Linkify.addLinks(view, pattern, CONTENT_URI.toString());
```

Where CONTENT_URI refers to a [ContentProvider](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html) you have registered in your manifest.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do the replaces. `Html.fromHtml` already handles the tags properly.

Comment: How can `Html.fromHtml` know I want #tag and @user to start SearchTagActivity and ShowUserActivity when user clicks them?

Comment: Oh, wait. I forgot to provide the patterns. First post edited.